# ng-select Add Tag not working when resolved inside an observable

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I need to implement a case where a tag is only added when user approves it in a seperate modal i.e when user clicks on addTag, a modal is going to open which will ask the user if he wants to proceed. Only, if he clicks on proceed the tag should be added.

When user clicks on proceed addCustomField subject emits a new value

```
addCustomField = curry(
    (formControlName: string, fieldToBeValidated: string) => {
      this.searchField.emit(fieldToBeValidated);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.service.addCustomField().subscribe((addTag) => {
          console.log(addTag, 'Add tag');
          resolve(fieldToBeValidated);
        });
      });
    }
```

```
<ng-select [items]="items"
           [addTag]="addCustomField"
           [bindLabel]="'name'"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
</ng-select>
```

Why is the tag not getting added on resolve? The console statement is getting printed?

It works with setTimeout but not with observable subscription

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to right

```
<ng-select [items]="items"
       [addTag]="addCustomField"
       [bindLabel]="name"
       [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
</ng-select>
```

?

Comment: Avoid asking questions by posting an answer, ask as a comment instead

Comment: I coudn't post a comment because I have not enought points